# How to set a fixed date with JodaTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm looking for any way to create a fixed day to month using JodaTime. I have a JSpinner to set integer values and I want get this value and create the Date. For example: JSpinner has 15, I want to create the date `2016-09-15`, `2016-10-15`, `2016-11-15`.

How could I do this using JodaTime ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes. The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

### `java.time.LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

You can specify the year, month, and day-of-month.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 15 );
```

You can switch months. The java.time classes use the [Immutable Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern, so a new fresh object is generated based on values of the original.

```
LocalDate september = ld.withMonth( 9 ); // 1-12 for January-December.
```

You can add/subtract months.

```
LocalDate nextMonth = ld.plusMonths( 1 );
LocalDate priorMonth = ld.minusMonths( 1 );
```

You can take any LocalDate and adjust the day to the 15th.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
LocalDate fifteenthThisMonth = today.withDayOfMonth( 15 );
```

Trap for a [`DateTimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DateTimeException.html) being thrown in the case of a day-of-month number invalid for that month, such as 31 for February.

By the way, you may find the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) or [`MonthDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) classes handy, and the [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum too.

## Joda-Time

If you must use Joda-Time, it offers a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class quite similar to `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate( 2016 , 1 , 7 );
LocalDate fifteenthSameMonth = ld.withDayOfMonth( 15 );
```